# How to configure the Spring spring-ws-core-2.2.3.RELEASE and xmlschema-core-2.2.1?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I have below two dependencies in my POM file.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the application it throws the below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
```

In xmlschema-core.2.2.1 has the read method as below

```
 public XmlSchema read(InputSource inputSource)
  {
    return read(inputSource, null);
  }
```

They have import the InputSource from org.xml.sax.InputSource.
But Spring throws the error with `Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource` parameter. Here they are referring `Lorg` not `org`.

Can someone suggest me which version of spring-ws-core and xmlschema-care compatible to run the application without any issue...

I'm using WebSphere 7 and Rational Application Developer 9.